# Websocket repeat auth request on: Laravel + Echo + Pusher js

Tags: php, laravel, echo, broadcasting

После загрузки страницы использую алгоритм со скриптами подключения к каналам вещания, работает всё как надо, после инициализации авторизации к приватному каналу получаю либо ошибку, либо успешное прослушивание канала, но проблема в следующем:

> если авторизация не прошла успешно, то отправить повторно запрос на
> авторизацию через ajax уже не получается

Есть ли у ECHO возможность многоразовых отправок запроса на авторизацию к приватному каналу вещания БЕЗ перезагрузки страницы?

**Консоль:**

```
Echo.private('test')

POST http://localhost/broadcasting/auth 403 (Forbidden)

Echo.private('test')

Echo.private('test')
```

**php**

```
Broadcast::channel('test', function ($user) {
    return rand(0, 1);
});
```